# How to run spring boot project extracted war file without tomcat?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, jar, war

I am current using embedded tomcat. 
when i changes on any code always need to upload jar/war file in server instead of uploading single compiled class.
any solution for that run extracted war/jar files.
currently i am using this command

java -jar project.jar

Comment: Though it's not recommend, but can be done. Please visit this page https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

Comment: @SUMIT thanks for reply but it is lengthy process can we run spring boot application jar after extracted